# Using a parameter as the select of an xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt

I've got the following ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                (etc.) >
    <xsl:param name="Query"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <r:results>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Query">
                (etc.)
            </xsl:for-each>
        </r:results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want the value of the `Query` parameter to be the `select` of the `for-each`.

When I execute this transformation in C# I get ... `Expression must evaluate to a node-set`.

I know it's coming from the `select` because if I replace `$Query` with a hard-coded expression (the same value that I'm passing as the parameter value) it works fine.

Any ideas?  Is this even possible?

Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT is compiled, and does not (according to the standard) support XPath re-evaluation at runtime - only at compile-time.

Some processors, such as Saxon, do have extensions to allow this, although they run with some limitations.  You might want to check out the [.Net version of the Saxon XSLT processor](http://www.saxonica.com/) ([.Net API page](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/dotnet/dotnetapi.html)). Saxon has an extension function called [saxon:evaluate](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/evaluate.html) which lets you do runtime XPath construction and evaluation.

The built-in Microsoft XSLT engine does not support calculated `select` XPath expressions.

One work-around is to build the XSLT as a string, substitute in your path, and then run it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only if your query is in an xml format. For e.g.  (the eg below is taken from the input format reqd by [SharePoint APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms471093.aspx) )

```
<Query>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
  </OrderBy>
  <Where>
    <Or>
      <Neq>
        <FieldRef Name="Status"></FieldRef>
        <Value Type="Text">Completed</Value>
      </Neq>
      <IsNull>
        <FieldRef Name="Status"></FieldRef>
      </IsNull>
    </Or>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Here in your xslt you can write:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Query/OrderBy">
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Query/descendant-or-self::node()">
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Query/child::node()">
```

The error " Expression must evaluate to a node-set" means that it should be in a proper xml format so that select can work on the nodes returned by the expression.